# Proper maven dependency for my stable python library from github into main java web app build

Tags: java, python, windows, eclipse, maven

I have a Vaadin Java web app build in eclipse. I also have a python library managed separately which I now integrate into my java web app. This works using a folder for python code within my web app code.

Now: I want to properly manage my python code separately from my github with versions and want to build the Java web app including a specific version of this python code (i.e. stable release) to continue working on the python code toward the next stable release without interference with the web app (just standard version control of a main app and a separate library I control and develop).

My experience so far is to include third-party dependencies for my Java web app but none are my own. I now want to use this same method for my own separate libraries.

Q: What is the proper way to express a Maven dependency in my Java Web app build with my Python code sitting on Github so that I do not need to manually include the python code within my web app repo?

If this has been answered, please point me to the best post, many thanks!

EDIT:

Following the comments received, it looks like my assumption to use Maven for solving the separate versioning of a set of files in my Java app is not the way to go. I am therefore opting to make my Java app project depend on the Python project in Eclipse where I can ensure to checkout only the stable version of the Python files to affect the Java build accordingly.

If this makes sense, we can close this question, many thanks for the comments and assistance.

Comment: A dependency in Maven is usually a java dependency not a python dependency...the question which comes into my mind: Why is the python code needed? Why not java code?

Comment: Well I may need to broaden my question further: How can I use maven to bring in "any files" from a separate github repo from my java build, using a specific tag or branch for those other files? It does not have to be python. Does this help ?

Comment: Not really in the end because Maven or more accurate a Maven repository are not general purpose stores for files...they have a particular intention but technically you can add/store a file along with a pom file ([build-helper-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) but I would not recommend it. The question is more why not implementing the parts in Java instead of Python? Really needed? Python has it's own package manager (pip)...

Comment: What about separating the python and Java parts in your build server (e.g. Jenkins)?

Comment: I see. Using Maven for merely streamlining integration of the latest version of a set of non-java files in my java build does not appear like the right thing to do. For now I will tag my python library code for versioning and will make my java app depend on the python project during build. This will achieve my main goal to evolve the python code in parallel of the web app.